# How to get artwork from MPMediaItemCollection

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection, mpmedialibrary

My goal is to get the cover picture for the playlists in iPod library. And I did something like

```
 playlistMediaItemCollections = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery().collections ?? []
 let artworks = playlistMediaItemCollections.map { $0.valueForKey(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork }
```

But it results in error

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist 0x1468b1eb0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key artwork.'
```

Anyone knows how I can get the playlist artwork? Thanks

Comment: @ozgur It's weird since you can actually pick a picture as the cover of a playlist.

Comment: Do you test on simulator or on a real device?

Comment: @ozgur on a real device. I created some playlists with covers to test that.

Comment: @ozgur yeah I guess so. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`valueForProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/valueForProperty:) instead:

```
$0.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork
```

However, I think unlike songs or albums, MediaPlayer API does not provide such property key that lets you retrieve the artwork of a playlist. You can check out possible [ones](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlaylist_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Playlist_Property_Keys) that can be used with MPMediaPlaylist class:

```
let MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID: String
let MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName: String
let MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPlaylistAttributes: String
let MPMediaPlaylistPropertySeedItems: String
```

One alternative is, you can get artworks of songs in the playlist, and show either one of them or combine them to create a new artwork for the playlist.

*I think  Music app does the same thing like below if a playlist doesn't have an artwork image.*

[image]

```
let playlist = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery().collections?.first
let artworks = playlist?.items.map { $0.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork }
```